# Abelian group structure on the set of isomorphism class of extensions

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

In Milne's CFT book, I saw that the second group cohomology $H^{2}(G, M)$ corresponds to the set of equivalence classes of extensions
$$
1\to M\to E\xrightarrow{\pi} G\to 1
$$
and the bijection is the following : for any given extension $E$, choose (set-theoretic) section $s:G\to E$ to $\pi:E\to G$. We give $G$-module structure on $M$ as
$$
\sigma\cdot m = s(\sigma)ms(\sigma)^{-1}
$$
This depends only on $\sigma$ since $M$ is abelian. Define $\varphi:G\times G\to M$ as
$$
\varphi(\sigma, \sigma') = s(\sigma)s(\sigma')s(\sigma\sigma')^{-1}.
$$
(The element is in $M$ since it is in $\ker(\pi)$.) Then $E\mapsto [\varphi]$ gives the desired bijection.

From this bijection we may inherit group structure of $H^{2}(G, M)$ to the set of the isomorphism classes, but I cannot understand this structure explicitly. The identity should corresponds to the trivial extension
$$
1\to M\to M\times G\to G\to 1,
$$
but the group operation is the problem. For given two extensions
$$
1\to M\to E_{1}\to G\to 1 \\
1\to M\to E_{2}\to G\to 1,
$$
how can we 'add' these to extensions? It may not be $E_{1}\times E_{2}$ or $E_{1}\otimes E_{2}$.

Comment: The operation is called Baer sum. A version of it is described here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#The_Baer_sum_of_extensions

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry for late reply. Thanks!